# Facebook Analytics for Apps -> Facebook Platform -> Sharing Insights. How to create API call for link shares

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

We have a business requirement to get all the Facebook engagement activity [shares, comments, likes] for websites. Every website has Facebook app id, and we want to do API call and display the data in a Google Spreadsheet for every site in weekly aggregates.

For that purpose, we are attaching following meta tag.

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="...">
```

Then we are able to see metrics on **Facebook Analytics for Apps -> Facebook Platform -> Sharing Insights**
[image]

It is really time-consuming to look for these numbers for every website. We want to automate this loading this metric by weekly basis. Ideally using API that will give us JSON which we can load into Google Spreadsheet.

We can not find a reference in Facebook docs for such an API.
We had a plan to use super metric Google Spreadsheet plugin but they have Facebook insights only for pages and we need it for Apps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get this data via API. [The App Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/app_insights) provides a wide array of metrics including clicks, comments, likes, publishes.